# uninstalling rvm can kill ruby versions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, installation, rvm

I was forced to uninstall then reinstall `rvm` but now when I run `rvm use 2.0.0`, I get a message telling me that this version is not installed. But, it is uninstalled if and only if the `rvm unistall all` killed the `ruby 2.0.0.` that was installed. Is it possible ?

Comment: run "rvm list" if it's not listed, then it's gone

Comment: If you remove rvm, you remove all of rvm's rubies.

Comment: @AndrewWei rvm list, I get No rvm rubies installed yet

Comment: @JesseWolgamott so `ruby -v` I get `ruby 1.8.7 `, so am I suppose to run : `rvm install ruby 2.0.0` ?

Comment: you should read this https://rvm.io/rvm/install, it's worth the read.

Comment: ok now, running `rvm install ruby 2.0.0` I get `/opt/local/bin/port: port selfupdate failed: Error synchronizing MacPorts sources: command execution failed`...

Comment: You should likely `rvm implode` and start your install over. (if nothing rvm works for you).

Comment: @AndrewWei your error might be related to [autolibs](https://rvm.io/rvm/autolibs) or [macports](https://rvm.io/integration/macports)

Answer (score 0):

By default all rubies / gems are stored inside of `$rvm_path` directory which is called 'self contained' and means removing RVM will also remove all related stuff.

It is configurable, you can choose to install RVM rubies and gemset locations with:

```
rvm_rubies_path=/opt/rubies
rvm_gems_path=/opt/rvm_gemsets
```

put it either in `~/.rvmrc` or `/etc/rvmrc` - this directories have to exist and need to be writable for users that will use them, use `chmod g+ws` and a group that is common for multiple users so different users can nstall and remove rubies / gems.